# Opening a JTextArea when a button is clicked

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a program that contains many buttons and when I click one of them, I want it to open a JTextArea with some txt file info in it. I tried to add the JTextArea to the button but it didn't open anything. I'm new in Java so I don't know if this is the correct approach to take.

I defined the button and JTextArea in the GUI

```
showListButton.add(jTextArea);
```

And here is the code I wrote inside of public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

```
if(e.getSource() == showListButton){



          try {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
                String word;
                while((word= in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                     jTextArea.read( in, null );
                     jTextTextArea.requestFocus();

                }
                in.close();
            }catch(IOException e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: "I'm new in Java" - that in combination with trying to build a UI right away is a receipe for headaches. You might want to try simpler things on the command line first and once you've grasped the basics head for UI territory. As for your question: you don't _add_ the text area to a button but to some container, e.g. a panel. For showing it there'd be at least 2 possibilities:  in the button's action/action listener you 1) add the text area to the relevant container (keep in mind that there's a layout manager) or 2) you grab a reference of the text area and set `visible` to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display something you need a root container like a `Window` or a `Jframe`. To
display your textarea you have add it in another frame that you will display on click or add it an already displayed panel.